# Python: Set keyframe for power or energy for the selected lights

Tags: python

Couldn't find answer to this, so I created this question and answered it.

So, how to set keyframe for power or energy for the selected lights?

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy

for light in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    #light.data.energy = 0  #uncomment this to set specific amount for all the lights
    light.data.keyframe_insert("energy")
```